# Css not aligning paragraph correctly

Tags: css, margin, font-size

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="copyright">
    <p>Copyright 2013 - All rights reserved</p></div>
```

---

```
    .copyright {
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         font-family: 'NeouBold';
         font-size: 13px;}
```

---

For some reason, the margin-left and margin-right will not center the paragraph.

Like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94786808/error.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
.copyright {
    text-align: center;
     font-family: 'NeouBold';
     font-size: 13px;}
```

Comment: I found that setting the width to "width: 300px;" did the trick.

Comment: sure. but text-align: center is less code to write and process. Also, you're not limited by the width and could bullet-proof it if your width was flexible.

Comment: cheers. You set text-align: center when you need to center the content of a container (text in a div or paragraph). You use fixed width and margin-left, margin-right auto when you need to center the whole container (div or paragraph here) in relation to it's parent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the div a width before centering with auto margins, as block-level elements take up 100% width by default

```
 .copyright {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-family: 'NeouBold';
 font-size: 13px;
 width: 300px;
 }
```

Comment: It's the simple? I'll try that! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try 
      {margin:0 auto}

Comment: I found that setting the width to "width: 300px;" did the trick.